# how to add css to multiple divs in a row and one after another with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am adding css background to multiple `divs` and I want to do it in a row and one after another. Now that I add css to all `divs`, it adds all the `background-images` to all `divs` at once which makes the images to load slowly.

this is my jquery code :

```
$('#m-portfolio .slick-slide').each(function(){
    var $item   = $(this),
        img     = $item.find('.m-p-view').attr('data-lazyload'),
        bg      = $item.find('.m-p-view').attr('data-bg');

    $item.find('div.slice').css('background-image', 'url(' + img + ')');
    $item.find('.m-p-view').css('background-image', 'url(' + bg + ')');    
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - **demo**: https://so.lucafilosofi.com/how-to-add-css-to-multiple-divs-in-a-row-and-one-after-another-with-jquery/

```
$(function () {
    $('#m-portfolio .slick-slide').each(function (i, item) {
        var $item = $(this).hide(),
            $mpview = $item.find('.m-p-view'),
            $slice = $item.find('.slice'),
            img = $mpview.attr('data-lazyload'),
            bg = $mpview.attr('data-bg');
        $('<img src="' + img + '" />').load(function () {
            $slice.css('background-image', 'url(' + img + ')');
            $('<img src="' + bg + '" />').load(function () {
                $mpview.css('background-image', 'url(' + bg + ')').parent('.slick-slide').delay(i + '000').fadeIn();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: what is div slice? Is a preview Image before the bigger one load? Not Exactly. Both of them are div backgrounds. One div is upper than another. When I click on the upper, it folds like a paper and the lower background shows up. Now, the problem is something else. I have got for example 10 elements like this with the same classes and because of that I used `each` and I dont want them to load at once together

Comment: Thanks. Not exactly, but this is somehow what I need. I am going to work on it

Comment: @Afshin Haghighat : with `load()` function you will sure that image is fully loaded before it display, so no flickering image will appear. then if you pre-set the `.m-p-view` to `hidden`, with the help of `fadeIn()` function you can make it display one after another at specified time using the `i` to increment each single item. This is because rendering of images is even faster then you can think, for this reason also if you `load()` all the images you will not see a real one-by-one effect that for istance you can achieve with fading effect.

Comment: @Afshin Haghighat i have updated the code tu suit your need, try it and let me know.